# c# UDP check if i got the whole packet?

Tags: c#, udp

Well this is my first udp test program and i think i now understand a bit of it :)
any way here is my code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Socket udpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            udpSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 111));
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024*64];
            int count = udpSocket.Receive(buffer);
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 111);
            EndPoint endPoint = (EndPoint)ipEndPoint;
            udpSocket.ReceiveFrom(buffer, ref endPoint);

            Console.WriteLine("Message recived from, " + endPoint.ToString() + " data length: " + count);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
```

but how do i make sure that i got the whole packet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have room for packets up to 64k bytes , which is the max size of a UDP packet. You'll always read the entire packet.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to check the length field in the [UDP header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol#Packet_structure) to see if you got enough bytes.

Comment: well i have no idea how i would do that?